# Using Google Earth KMZ file in Power BI, vector and Earth images combined

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz, power-bi

I have a Power BI project that contains a KML file from Google  Earth (kmz file). I just need the Power BI to show the shape in the same way Google Earth shows it. When I try to put it in Power BI I lost the satellite feature presented by the Google Earth software, I just get the vector/polygon map with no satellite image.

Is it possible to present the KML file in Power BI in the same way Google Earth presents it?

I uploaded a video to try to explain it better...

link with the question:
https://youtu.be/hp1zry38EZM

Comment: Kmz, is a zipped KML file not a shapefile

Comment: I know the difference, I had to converted it in ArcGis to open in Google Earth. But I wanted to use Power BI to open the KMZ file just like it is opened in Google Earth, with satellite imagery over the boundaries originally made by the shape file. I would be very happy and grateful if you could help me!

Comment: Good that you know the difference,  the issue is clarity in the question.  Are you saying that the KML holds both the vector information and also the raster information.  For the latter is the actual raster/image or is it a reference to the image?

Comment: Nope, the Google Earth does not carry any raster information... it just uses the shape (KMZ) boundaries information and projects it on their earth satellite images.

Comment: Is the imagery just the Google Earth satellite imagery, not imagery that you have loaded yourself, say from a WMS?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Create-Your-Own-Custom-Map-for-Power-BI/td-p/165854

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. It is always best to include the instructions with a reference to the source so that your post remains viable even if the link goes 404.

Comment: I don't think the linked content answers the question though.  The issue is not how to get vector data from KML to GeoJSON, the issue concerns satellite imagery